# Interface with template member function

Tags: c++, oop, templates, functional-programming

I am interested in implementing a Java-collection-like environment for C++.
I know this isn't a good idea and so on but I don't really want to use it later, but just learn how to do some advanced OOP.

My problem is I want a base class template `collection<T>` with purely virtual functions. One of these functions should be `map()` which takes a  `std::function<R(T)>`. Since `map()` should be virtual I don't know which return type I should use for it. `collection<R>` isn't possible because member function templates can't be virtual.

How can I add such `map()` member function for my `collection<T>` interface?

Comment: What's wrong with c++ standard containers?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ OP is trying to do this for learning purposes i guess.

Comment: nothing I just want to know how to implement such a thing for educatial purpose

Comment: You will have to implement type-erasure in C++. Good luck.

Comment: There are already examples of type erasure in C++. See std:shared_ptr and std::function

Comment: It's simply a limitation of C++ object model. What you are looking for is basically a workaround, not advanced OOP stuff of any kind.

Comment: I don't get it - why are you mixing standard O-O inheritance (via virtual methods) with C++ style generic polymorphism?  The C++ approach is to use specialization (and overloading) with templates to achieve the effect of a set of closely related classes that can be used "nearly" interchangeably.  Or, you can implement a pure O-O ("java") approach without templates.  The thing to remember is that Java (and C#) generics are not the same mechanism as C++ templates.  In conclusion, what do you expect to get from a virtual template method  map that you can't get from a template method map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I add such `map` member function for my `collection<T>` interface?

The short answer is: you don't. If I have some `collection<int>` and I want to `map` `std::to_string` onto it, I need to produce a `collection<std::string>`. But a `vector_collection<int>` needs to produce a `vector_collection<std::string>` and a `list_collection<int>` needs to produce a `list_collection<std::string>` - so that type transformation itself needs to be `virtual`ized. But you can't have `virtual` member function templates, so there's no way to express this.

In order for this to work, you would have to have a common base type for all of the objects you're putting in your container and then just have a common facade that you could cast between. That is, you really only have `collection<unique_ptr<Object>>` where `map` just gives you a different `collection<unique_ptr<Object>>`, and you just `map` your `collection_facade<int, collection<unique_ptr<Object>>>` into a `collection_facade<std::string, collection<unique_ptr<Object>>>`. With a lot of work and complete disregard for performance and type safety, you could get there.

---

This is the advantage of templates. If I want to write `map` for something like `vector`, I can just write that:

```
template <class T, class A, class F, class R = std::result_of_t<F(T)>>
std::vector<R, A> map(std::vector<T, A> const& v, F f) {
    std::vector<R, A> mapped;
    mapped.reserve(v.size());
    for (T const& elem : v) {
        mapped.push_back(f(elem));
    }
    return mapped;
}
```

or:

```
template <class T, class A, class F, class R = std::result_of_t<F(T)>>
std::vector<R, A> map(std::vector<T, A> const& v, F f) {
    return std::vector<R, A>(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), f),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(v.end(), f)
        );
}
```

I have to implement `map()` for each container separately - but I would have to do that anyway. And now I'm not giving anything up. Besides, how often are you writing algorithms that are runtime-container-agnostic?

Comment: And `allocator` can also be rebound.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `map` as an external template function.
For instance, you can decompose `map` in two stages, internal virtual producer and external templated consumer.

```
template<typename T> struct Collection {
    // virtual T next(); // Java way
    // C++ way
    // In simplest cases you can rely on iterator pairs.
    struct const_iterator {
        T const &operator*() const;
        const_iterator &operator++();
    }
    virtual const_iterator begin() const;
    virtual const_iterator end() const;
};
template<typename R, typename T> Collection<R> map(
    Collection<T> const &coll, std::function<R(T)> const &f);
```

To implement essentially complicated containers and monadic compositions you can even deny `begin()` and `end()` and write an explicit (partial) template specialization.